# OutputDataReceived (and ErrorDataReceived) has a slow firing rate and creates a large buffer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, process

is there a way to increase the rate a **Process** object in .NET throws the **OutputDataReceived** event?  It creates a large buffer (I believe 1024 characters) that is dumped in bulk which makes the application not as fluid of a stream as I would of like it to be.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Process.OutputDataReceived` event is fired only in following two conditions.

1. Newline is encountered in output
2. Complete data is received

So if and only if you have a newline character in your output stream event will get fired else it will wait for complete data then the event will get fired.

I just tested it till 968000 bytes. Event is raised only after entire data is received as I have not kept any newline character in the output.

Comment: This info should be really added to MSDN. Reading - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, you can't be sure it works like this, only hint is example, but it's just hint of how it works, not specific explanation.